# How long is an Elastic IP valid in AWS? Is it terminated after sometime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, elastic-ip

How long is an Elastic IP valid in AWS? Is it terminated after sometime ?

I requested an elastic IP from AWS EC2 console and got one. How long can i use the elastic IP.? Will AWS take it back after sometime or will remain with me as long i have an AWS accoutn

Comment: What do you mean by valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Ip is valid till you don't release them manually from your account.

You will be charged for elastic IP if it is not associated with any instance. For more details visit http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Answer (score 1):

Elastic IP allocated to an account. You can associate/reassociate to any instance or you can leave the elastic IP without associating it to any instance. The elastic IP is **assigned to the account until you release it**.

For more information: [Elastic IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

You won't be charged as long as the elastc ip is associated with a **running** instance. Else you will be charged a small fee ($0.005/hour)

Comment: I didn't get charged for the first one. Can i keep it as long as i wish without associating it to any EC2 instance?

Comment: You won't be charged as long as the elastc ip is associated with a running instance. Else you will be charged a small fee ($0.005/hour)